# Sending different error messages from web service

Tags: web-services, soap, cxf

I wrote a web service using cxf web service. I want to send different error messages to client. I have a method and this method return an object if everything is ok. Method receives parameters if one of parameters is wrong, method must send different messages. But i can not change method return type so i cant send different objects. How can i do that?

Comment: Are you developing a JAX-RS or JAX-WS service?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the exceptions.
Within the java annotations cxf system you can return an exception if it looks like this :

```
import javax.xml.ws.WebFault;

@WebFault(name = "UsageMyException")
public class MyException extends Exception
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MyException(final String string)
    {
        super(string);
    }

    public MyException(final Exception e)
    {
        super(e);
    }
}
```

You can use more than one exception that extends each other. The exception corresponds to wsdl/soap `FaultMessage`.